# Cakephp loadmodel can't access multiple models from one controller

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, model

I'm working with cakephp, and i'm stuck.

I have two models : Place.php and Shelve.php

In my controller "PlacesController.php", I'm trying to do :

```
$this->loadModel('Shelve');
$shelves = $this->Shelve->find('all');
```

But it's says me on my index.ctp (it should list all the shelves I have in my database):

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Place.shelf_id' in 'field list'
```

How can I have all the records of  the Shelve model from my PlacesController ?

Tks !

Comment: Read the error message, it is more than clear if you just read it: **Unknown column 'Place.shelf_id'** add it or rename your foreign keys field name in the table or in your association declaration. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner with cakephp, I don't know exactly the rules to name the fields in the database. I was wrong, I change my database field and i don't hav the error now. Tks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP directly. It's a SQL error message. *Always* pay attention to any kind of error or notice message. You can name DB fields in Cake as you like but you'll have to tell the framework if you don't follow it's conventions. I really recommend you to read the documentation.

Comment: Just as @burzum said "It's an SQL error message" but if u still wanna access multiple model in one controller, one of the options is: public $uses = array('ModelOne', 'ModelTwo', '.....', 'ModelNth') just inside your controller class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

$registrationFees = $this->RegistrationFees->find('all',['contain' => ['Events'],'conditions' => ['Events.status' => 'yes']]);